# Accessing each part of an array using (change) Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a  box, where you can click on each option within it and it will filter through data coming from firebase database. So far, I have it working where you can click on each of them. However, I can only get it to perform one task.

Each of the options comes from this array:

```
items: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

and the filtering comes from this function:

```
filterByBedrooms(bedrooms: number) {
   this.bedFilter.next(bedrooms);
   console.log('clicked')
 }
```

and then I have this form where I call the function:

```
 <form  #fSearchPropertiesByBedrooms (change)="filterByBedrooms(items[4])">
          <select class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms">
            <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Beds</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> <button> {{item}} Bed </button> </option>
          </select>
          <!-- <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-xs button-green">Submit</button> -->
        </form>
```

Now obviously in this I bind to the function and the array like so:

```
(change)="filterByBedrooms(items[4])"
```

I am aware that what I need to do is somehow bind to it like this:

```
(change)="filterByBedrooms(item)"
```

However, the *ngFor comes after this part, so it does not work.

My question is, how do I bind (change) to each of the options (coming from the array) within my select box and not just one part of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't bind your event to your options, you bind it to your select.

You can see it for yourself : the select carries the `ngModel` attribute, not the options.

See it as an input of type text, with predefined results.

So simply call your method with the bound `ngModel` like this.

```
<select
  class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down"
  type="number"
  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms"
  name="bedrooms"
  (change)="filterByBedrooms(bedrooms)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, just declare an identifier for select and use the value in your method.

```
<form  #fSearchPropertiesByBedrooms (change)="filterByBedrooms(bedrooms.value)">
              <select class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" #bedrooms>
                <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Beds</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> <button> {{item}} Bed </button> </option>
              </select>
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-xs button-green">Submit</button> -->
            </form>
```

Also I noticed you have binded the variable bedrooms to select. That means that you have that variable in your controller so you can redefine your filterByBedrooms method to something like this

```
filterByBedrooms() {
   this.bedFilter.next(this.bedrooms);
   console.log('clicked')
 }
```

If you are using the second example than your form will look like this

```
<form  #fSearchPropertiesByBedrooms (change)="filterByBedrooms()">
                  <select class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" >
                    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Beds</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> <button> {{item}} Bed </button> </option>
                  </select>
                  <!-- <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-xs button-green">Submit</button> -->
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use (ngModelChange) event as far as you use ngModel binding, so the code should look like:

```
 <form  #fSearchPropertiesByBedrooms>
      <select class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" (ngModelChange)="filterByBedrooms($event)">
        <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Beds</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> <button> {{item}} Bed </button> </option>
      </select>
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-xs button-green">Submit</button> -->
    </form>
```

And actually I'm not sure you need a form for this particular control as I see you commented the submit button, so this can be simplified to:

```
  <select class="form-control form-control-lg small-drop-down" type="number"  [(ngModel)]="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" (ngModelChange)="filterByBedrooms($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected>Beds</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"> <button> {{item}} Bed </button> </option>
  </select>
```

Don't forget to add value check on filterByBedrooms function as in your case it can by invoked with undefined value.